# How to use constructor in Realm on Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I want use **`Realm`** for **Database** in android, and i create `provider class` to save values but when use this class **constructor** in main class (`activity`) show me this error, please see error from this image : [Error image Link](http://uploads.im/6MvQA.jpg)

**Task_Provider class :**

```
public class Task_Provider extends RealmObject {

    public Task_Provider() {
    }

    public String getAddTask() {
        return addTask;
    }

    public void setAddTask(String addTask) {
        this.addTask = addTask;
    }

    public long getAdded_date() {
        return added_date;
    }

    public void setAdded_date(long added_date) {
        this.added_date = added_date;
    }

    public long getWhen_date() {
        return when_date;
    }

    public void setWhen_date(long when_date) {
        this.when_date = when_date;
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public Task_Provider(String addTask, long added_date, long when_date, boolean complete) {
        this.addTask = addTask;
        this.added_date = added_date;
        this.when_date = when_date;
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    private String addTask;
    @PrimaryKey
    private long added_date;
    private long when_date;
    private boolean complete;

}
```

**Main Activity** (Button setOnClickListener) :

```
String addTask = dialog_edit_task.getText().toString();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Task_Provider task_provider = new Task_Provider(addTask, now, 0, false);

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(task_provider);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

How can i fix this problem? tnx all <3

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? This should be possible with v0.88.0 and above, but not below. A possible workaround would be using static factory method (`public static Task_Provider create(String addTask, long added_date, long when_date, boolean complete) {`) in place of your constructor.

Comment: "Realm supports as many custom constructors as you like as long as one of them is a public no arguments constructor." https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#creating-objects Custom constructor is always possible even before v0.88.0 as long as there is a public no arguments constructor :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Constructors **do** work and provide default values since Realm 2.0.0.

---

Previously:

```
public Task_Provider(String addTask, long added_date, long when_date, boolean complete) {
    this.addTask = addTask;
    this.added_date = added_date;
    this.when_date = when_date;
    this.complete = complete;
}
```

This didn't work because the Realm-Transformer couldn't execute the constructor for a RealmProxy before calling `super()`, so the right way to do it used to be

```
public Task_Provider() {
}


public static Task_Provider create(String addTask, long added_date, long when_date, boolean complete) {
    Task_Provider taskProvider = new Task_Provider();
    taskProvider.addTask = addTask;
    taskProvider.added_date = added_date;
    taskProvider.when_date = when_date;
    taskProvider.complete = complete;
    return taskProvider;
}
```

Then you can do

```
Task_Provider taskProvider = Task_Provider.create(...);
```

Comment: This is cool. Do you know anyway of automating it so I don't have to type it out each time (Similar to insert code)

Comment: @GideonSassoon this might help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/replace-constructor-with-factory-method.html ( REFACTOR -> REPLACE CONSTRUCTOR WITH FACTORY METHOD ), but make sure you keep a no-arg public constructor if you use RealmObjects.

Comment: When it creates it still keeps the old constructor and in fact uses it. In this scenario would I leave it be and just add as you suggested a no-arg public constructor?

Comment: You definitely need a no-arg constructor because Realm uses it in `realm.createObject()` and `realmResults.get(i)`.