# Custom constructor error with Realm model class

Tags: android, realm

Realm throws the following error message if you have a custom constructor within the Realm model class.

> Class `<class name>` must declare a public constructor with no arguments if it contains custom constructors

Below is the Realm model class.

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

public User(Integer id, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
}
```

How do you get rid of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use constructor in Realm on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261888/how-to-use-constructor-in-realm-on-android)

Comment: @Vishal I'm guessing it's the same error, although the picture doesn't exist anymore to show what the original error was. Thought I'd make it easy to find a solution to this error on search engines by posting another question with the error within it and a solution for the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm requires every Realm model class to have a public constructor with no arguments. This is because of the method [`createObject(Class<E> clazz)`](https://realm.io/docs/java/4.1.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createObject-java.lang.Class-). For example, to get the User class to work, it'd look like the following.

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

public User() {

}

public User(Integer id, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
}
```